# How can I search for OP_RETURN data?

Tags: op-return

Is there any way to check for this data in blockchain?

I want to search this value: 554e6963444320 and want to return this transaction https://blockchain.info/tx/7e92e90f221ad28daf42b5b8bda4c8e244e37af48527fcd12b2518db5d3315bd

Comment: This will require parsing the blockchain and looking for your data string to match transaction(s) which contain that data. Building an index of all op_return transactions could speed this greatly, but to my knowledge it is not yet available as a service or product.

Comment: How to identify transactions with op_return?

Answer (score 2):

The [Chain.com API](https://chain.com/docs) offers functionality for returning *OP_RETURN* data by:

1. [Address](https://api.chain.com/v2/bitcoin/addresses/1Bj5UVzWQ84iBCUiy5eQ1NEfWfJ4a3yKG1/op-returns?api-key-id=DEMO-4a5e1e4)
2. [TxID](https://api.chain.com/v2/bitcoin/transactions/4a7d62a4a5cc912605c46c6a6ef6c4af451255a453e6cbf2b1022766c331f803/op-return?api-key-id=DEMO-4a5e1e4)
3. [Block height](https://api.chain.com/v2/bitcoin/blocks/308920/op-returns?api-key-id=DEMO-4a5e1e4)

The JSON return data from the REST API has a `text` field which is meant to be the decoded hex data sent (ie ``` 6a``hex data ```) but it's returned in the format ``` \\x``hex data ```.

In Python you can simply do this:

```
import __future__
import requests; from binascii import unhexlify
rdata = requests.get("https://api.chain.com/v2/bitcoin/addresses/%s/op-returns?api-key-id=DEMO-4a5e1e4" % "1Bj5UVzWQ84iBCUiy5eQ1NEfWfJ4a3yKG1") # substitute URL here
assert rdata.status_code == 200
jdata = rdata.json()
hexdata = [unhexlify(str(t["text"]).encode("utf-8"))) for t in jdata
print(hexdata)
```

Comment: How would I do a search in the bitcoin core?

Comment: api.chain.com doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 2):

This Blockchain explorer: https://blockchair.com/ allows you to search for embedded data in 19 different Blockchains. And on this URL https://bitcoinstrings.com/all I think you can get all embedded texts.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it via https://www.smartbit.com.au/ that already parses all the data including op_returns

Comment: It's now offline